# Parsing XML with multi-line records

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

I'd like to take XML in the format below and load each code record into a domain object in my `BootStrap.groovy`.  I want to preserve the formatting of each snippet of code.

### XML

```
<records>
    <code>
        <language>Groovy</language>
        <snippet>
            println "This is Groovy"
            println "A very powerful language"
        </snippet>
    </code>
    <code>
        <language>Groovy</language>
        <snippet>
            3.times {
                println "hello"
            }
        </snippet>
    </code>
    <code>
        <language>Perl</language>
        <snippet>
            @foo = split(",");
        </snippet>
    </code>
</records>
```

### Domain Object

```
Code {
    String language
    String snippet
}
```

### BootStrap.groovy

```
new Code(language l, snippet: x).save()
```

Comment: I fixed up the formatting a bit, I hope you don't mind, and that I haven't unwittingly changed the semantics of your post, though.. (please feel free to revert it if I have!)

Comment: heh - we both edited it at the same time. i was faster and i lost :(

Comment: Oops, sorry fella. Glad to see we both made pretty much the same changes, though ;). I'm surprised that the site doesn't inform you if the post has been edited since you started messing with it.. Clobbering other people's changes isn't good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

roughly something like this:

```
def CODE_XML = '''
<records>
    <code>
        <language>Groovy</language>
        <snippet>
            println "This is Groovy"
            println "A very powerful language"
        </snippet>
    </code>
    <code>
        <language>Groovy</language>
        <snippet>
            3.times {
                println "hello"
            }
        </snippet>
    </code>
    <code>
        <language>Perl</language>
        <snippet>
            @foo = split(",");
        </snippet>
    </code>
</records>
  '''
def records = new XmlParser().parseText(CODE_XML)
records.code.each() { code ->
    new Code(language: code.language, snippet: code.snippet).save()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can specity a DTD or similar and your XML parser obeys it, I think you can specify the contents of the snippet element to be CDATA and always get it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `xml:space="preserve"` attribute to `<snippet>` elements.